# Division of force and acceleration!

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, vectors

As you would know that $\text {Force}= \text {mass} \times \text {acceleration}$. So $\text  {mass}= \text {force}\div{\text {acceleration}}$.
Now both force and acceleration are vectors. But their is no such thing as vector division. So how can we define mass as $\text {force}\div{\text {acceleration}}$?

Comment: You are dividing the magnitude of these vectors, which is just division of one scalar by another. You are right that vector division is not a defined operation, but that is not what you're doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\vec F= m\vec a$, we know that direction of $\vec F$ and $\vec a$ are same.

Let's define a unit vector such that $$\vec u = \frac{\vec F}{|\vec F|} = \frac{\vec a}{|\vec a|}$$ Now, $$\vec F=|\vec F|\vec u$$ and $$\vec a=|\vec a|\vec u$$Mass m can be repersented as vector dot product as, $$m=\vec F.\vec X$$ where $\vec X=\frac{1}{|\vec a|}\vec u$

$$\implies m=\frac{|\vec F|}{|\vec a|}\vec u.\vec u$$
$$\implies m=\frac{|\vec F|}{|\vec a|}$$

This way vector division can be represented as dot product, probably why physicists and mathematicians didn't define vector division.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\vec F= m\vec a$ this would imply $| \vec F|= m|\vec a|$. And since magnitude of a vector is scalar, we can say $$m=\frac{|\vec F|}{|\vec a|}$$